# CommandLineParser does not accept arguments with minus characters inside

Tags: c++, opencv

This is my `main.cpp` source code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;

const char* keys = {
    "{@command  ||}"
    "{@input    ||}"
    "{@argument ||}"
};

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keys);

    String param0 = parser.get<String>(0);
    String param1 = parser.get<String>(1);
    String param2 = parser.get<String>(2);

    cout << param0 << " | " << param1 << " | " << param2;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code like this:

```sh
./main --bright ./image.png -10
```

I expect the output is:

```sh
--bright | ./image.png | -10
```

but the output is:

```sh
./image.png |  |
```

I do not know how to fix it. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Probably an issue with your shell consuming the `|` on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at the [CommandLineParser](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d2e/classcv_1_1CommandLineParser.html#ad0bb71c0bc9800e90bfdc44ff406293e) documentation before starting.

If you just change those 3 lines with the following one, you will get the desired output:

```
cv::String param0 = cv::String(argv[1]);
cv::String param1 = cv::String(argv[2]);
cv::String param2 = cv::String(argv[3]);
```

Actually `argv` is an array and store all the command units you type in terminal.

Comment: this merely *circumvents* OpenCV's `CommandLineParser`. it does not explain how to achieve the desired behavior *with* CommandLineParser.